# Determining Non-Trivial Ideal 0f L(V)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Prove that If  $dim_F$ $(V ) > 1$ be finite, prove that $L(V )$ has two sided ideals other than $(0)$ and $L(V )$.

Further

Prove that the conclusion above is false if $V$ is not finite dimensional over $F$.

If  $dim_F$ $(V ) > 1$.Then let $v_1,v_2$ be two basis elements of $V$.The I tried making an ideal of $L(V )$ using these two basis elements but I was unsucessful.

Please help me with the problem.I tried the last part too but wasn't sucessful

---

Note that the above is **false** as written. See the dupliacte for the correct assertion.